# SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found 'Connected' instead

Tags: php, html, database, syntax

I have a simple error that I just cannot figure out why I am getting it.
Any idea why I might get

```
SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found 'Connected' instead
```

I'm using Safari, but I have tried in Google Chrome.
I must make it work with Safari.

The Code:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'student');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Database Connected successfully';
?>
```

The Code that calls the above

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Check if the page has loaded completely  priere to 2 seconds of the page being fully       loaded
$(document).ready( function() { 
setTimeout( function() { 
    $('#displayconnection').load('js/dbconnect.php'); 
}, 2000);   
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: I think the error is outside of this lines.

Comment: The source file is correct and can't print the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web browser should not influence whether the PHP code runs or not. Also, this isn't JavaScript.

Make sure the file can be executed by your server (does it have a `.php` extension)?

---

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $.get('js/dbconnect.php', function(data) {
      $('#displayconnection').text(data);
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: It does, but I will check to make sure. I'm using it on my locally at the moment until I get it perfection then adding to our Main Server (LAMP)

Comment: It isn't being executed. You shouldn't be able to see the PHP code from the web browser.

Comment: I check the security setting, it is set to read and executable